# accessing box2d bodies

Tags: javascript, box2d

Since now, I've been accessing box2d bodies (to change or to get their values) with this for loop copied from the web:

```
for (var b = world.GetBodyList(); b != null; b = b.GetNext())
```

works fine but... Is there any other faster way to do so? Can't I just store a reference to the bodies in an array so then have always access to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which version of Box2DJs you're using but you can do something like this:

```
var myBodies = [];
var myBox = new b2BoxDef(); // or whatever the name of your body creation function is
myBodies.push(myBox);
console.log(myBodies[0]); // reference to your Box2D object
```

Comment: thanks! so, could I getPosition and applyImpulse to myBodies[0]?
Will this work?

Will try it asap!

Comment: @Saturnix: Yep, everything you'd normally do to your bodies.